# Dropdown login form ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, form

Хочу сделать `dropdown` для логина у себя в приложении. Вот, как это выглядит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Dropdown` будет находится в `navbar`, следовательно я пишу код в `Layout page`.

**Вот код формы логина:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="@Schedule.Resources.HomeTexts.Log_In" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Проблема в том, что я использую `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email...` для этого нужна модель, когда я подключаю модель в `Layout` (`@model Schedule.BLL.Model.LoginModel`) выдает вот такую ошибку:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type 'System.Exception', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'Schedule.BLL.Model.LoginModel'.

Как ее можно исправить? Или как лучше реализовать `Dropdown login form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Я использовал частичное представление:  `@Html.Partial("LoginPartial", new Schedule.BLL.Model.LoginModel())`

В файле **LoginPartial** находится код формы логина. Я вызываю частичное представление в `layout`, а в качестве параметра передаю модель.